# add a new property to a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

i have a list and want to add two new properties after the list is populated.

can this be done?

**C# List**

```
List<Usp_GetListItemsBySystemResult> PendingListOfItemsToControl = new List<Usp_GetListItemsBySystemResult>(); // Items to Control in Running memory 

// Get items to Control into running memory
FAItemsUnderControl fItemsUnderControl = new FAItemsUnderControl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseConnectionString"]);
PendingListOfItemsToControl = fItemsUnderControl.getItemsUnderControl(DropDownListSystems.Text.ToString(), "ALL").ToList<Usp_GetListItemsBySystemResult>();

// Add new paramaters to the list here ????????
```

**C# new properties to add**

```
    public string ItemRequestStatus { get; set; } // Determines the change status if applicable
    public bool IsButtonEnabled { get; set; } // Determines if the delete button is enabled or disabled
```

**C# class**

```
public class Usp_GetListItemsBySystemResult
{
    public Usp_GetListItemsBySystemResult();

    public DateTime? Creation_DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Item_Backup_Location { get; set; }
    public string Item_Category { get; set; }
    public short? Item_Check_Interval_Time { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Item_Creation_DateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Item_Last_Access_DateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Item_Last_Modified_DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Item_Name { get; set; }
    public string Item_Path { get; set; }
    public int? Item_Size { get; set; }
    public string Item_Status { get; set; }
    public string Item_Value { get; set; }
    public string Item_Value_SHA256 { get; set; }
    public int? ItemUnderControl_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It might be a language thing, but your question doesn't make any sense.  `List`s don't have "parameters" so I can't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Do you need the properties as part of your list of as part of the class?

Comment: Why not add them to the class and set them as needed?

Comment: @user1438082 - Give us an example of how you would like to set `ItemRequestStatus` and it might make more sense for us.  All three answers which are currently below are perfectly possible answers to your question, even though they all do very different things.

Comment: I don't understand why the objects in your list are called `Usp_GetListItemsBySystemResult` and in reading the answers, I think the name is creating some confusion.

Comment: i need to add the new paramaters to be added to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your own `MyList` class  with these 2 properies inherited from `List`.
Something like this:

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    public string ItemRequestStatus { get; set; } // Determines the change status if applicable
    public bool IsButtonEnabled { get; set; } // Determines if the delete button is enabled or disabled

    public MyList()
    {

    }

    public MyList(IList<T> list)
        : base(list)
    {

    }
}
```

usage:

```
FAItemsUnderControl fItemsUnderControl = new FAItemsUnderControl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseConnectionString"]);
var list = fItemsUnderControl.getItemsUnderControl(DropDownListSystems.Text.ToString(), "ALL").ToList<Usp_GetListItemsBySystemResult>();
MyList<Usp_GetListItemsBySystemResult> PendingListOfItemsToControl = new MyList<Usp_GetListItemsBySystemResult>(list);
```

Comment: Depends if he wants it on the `List` or on the object stored in the `List`.  The question is unclear, but this is the less common scenario.

Comment: can you give me an example please?

Comment: i want it on the list. ultimately i am going to bnd the 'new' list to a gridview

Comment: @user1438082 wrote it, I don't know, should these properties depend on data in your list?

Comment: hi, can you elaborate on how to  inherit from my base class and proceed to put PendingListOfItemsToControl results into this new object?

Comment: i put this code in but the 2 new properties do not exist in PendingListOfItemsToControl when i hover over it in visual studio after the code has ran.

Answer (score 1):

You can create this class and using Linq to add values to this new properties.

```
List<NewClass> = from x in GetListItemsBySystemResult 
                select new NewClass{
                  Creation_DateTime = x.Creation_DateTime ,
                  ...,
                  ItemRequestStatus = "Value",
                  IsButtonEnabled = "Value",
                  };
```

Then in this new List you have populated with the new values.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an expando object and add whatever you want to it:

```
var myx = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
myx.Add("NewProp", string.Empty);
```